Parsing それとも俺の経験と想像力が足りないだけで
I am not sure how to parse それとも俺の経験と想像力が足りないだけで. I initially parsed it as

それとも((俺の経験)と(想像力))が足りないだけで

but I later realized that it makes more sense to understand that way:

それとも(俺の経験)と(想像力が足りないだけ)で

I treated だけ as a noun here. Is that correct?


「それとも[{俺の(経験と想像力)}が足りない]だけで」とはならないですかね？

@chocolate Ah thanks this is almost like my first one. You are saying that it is correct?

Your initial reading is close, but strictly speaking, it's 俺の((経験)と(想像力)), or "my experience and (my) imagination". Two nouns are simply connected using と ("and").

それとも俺の経験と想像力が足りないだけで、意外と兄妹で一緒に水着を買いに行くのは普通なのか？
Or is it just that I lack the experience and imagination (to realize this)... Is it actually normal for a brother and a sister to go shopping for swimsuits together?

